# Woocommerce orderby rand with tax_query not random

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, tax-query

I would like to change the related products section on my woocommerce products details page so it only displays related child category products (**not** products that only have the parent category in common).  For Example:

- Parent Cat

  - Child 1 Cat
  - Child 2 Cat
  - Child 3 Cat

If a user is visiting a product details page that is categorized under "Parent Category -> Child 1 Cat" all the user is viewing are "Child 1 Cat" products.

I am attempting to modify the `woocommerce/single-product/related.php` file inside of my theme folder using the following php scripts to accomplish this behavior:

```
$product_cat_slugs = array();
foreach (get_the_terms($product->ID, 'product_cat') as $term) {
    if($term->slug !== 'skip-this-cat') {
        array_push($product_cat_slugs, $term->slug);
    }
}

$args = array(
    'post_type'            => 'product',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'  => 1,
    'no_found_rows'        => 1,
    'posts_per_page'       => 4,
    'orderby'              => 'rand',
    'post__not_in'         => array( $product->id ),
    'tax_query'            => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                'field'    => 'slug',
                                'terms'    => $product_cat_slugs
                            )
                          )
);


$products = new WP_Query( $args );
```

The categorization is correct, but my problem is that I am not getting back a random set of posts.  I'm only receiving the same posts each load.

Comment: Are you sure there are *more than* 4 products for the given query?

Comment: Yes, there are about 120 products right now total and more than four under each child category.  It seems like the randomize only stops working when the tax_query lines are added.

Comment: I think we've found your problem - if the tax_query "breaks" the randomization, then it's because there aren't more than 4 products that match _all_ the categories (other than `skip-this-cat`) of the current product

Comment: The 'skip-this-cat' is the parent category.  I'm trying to get all the other categories from a specific post besides that parent category.  I'll do some test output to confirm the category slug array, but the products I have entered I only have one or two categories per product and I only have a total of 5 categories, so there are plenty of products inside of each category.

Comment: Can't you just randomize the [`$query->posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Methods_and_Properties) directly? Or... you're saying it would be the same 4 each time... nm.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic - I confirmed that there are more than 4 products in each child category by increasing the posts_per_page.  My problem is that the order still does randomize.

Comment: @jgraup - that might work...I could query using  'posts_per_page'  => -1 or something and then resort.  Do you have any idea how to resort once you get the query object?  I can imagine that query being very slow over time too, so it might be best to write some custom query.

Comment: @adam2k - try `shuffle( $query->posts )` after the query. Or pick a random page offset and keep your posts in order. I've reordered the query before. I think it only gets tricky if you're adding/removing content from that collection.

Comment: @jgraup sweet! I was trying everything, but the shuffle seemed to work.  I think I just have to make a counter for loop now and break out after 4 iterations.  Is there something in the wordpress codex about pruning posts after a query?  I tried `array_splice($query->posts, 4);` but that doesn't seem to have the desired results.  It looks like that's only removing the post data.

Comment: $current_post on the $query will hold your counter index in the loop.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query. You may have to set the collection directly to modify the length which means doing splice operations on a temporary variable, then setting $posts to that variable - IDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the WP_Query was correct.  I am hosting with WP_Engine and I had to contact their support desk and have the ticket elevated to resolve the issue.  Apparently the query, even with the `'orderby' => 'rand'`, was being cached by their servers.  I should have contacted them earlier, but I thought it was something that I was doing incorrectly in my query.  Thanks all for the help!